# Apply conditions in Ajax success Method on received data from Django's view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-ajax-selects

I'm working on a Django project in which I need to handle a form via ajax.I'm sending ajax request to Django view and getting back the response in JSON format, now I need to apply if-else conditions on that data but these conditions are not working, always run the first condition in any case.

Here's my code:

**Django's view:**

```
            auth = getauth()
            service = discovery.build('cloudbilling', 'v1', http=auth, cache_discovery=False)
            name = 'projects/' + projectName
            billing_request = service.projects().getBillingInfo(name=name,)
            billing_response = billing_request.execute()
            data = billing_response
            print(json.dumps(data))

            if 'billingAccountName' in data:
                b_response = data
                b_response['msg'] = True
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(b_response), content_type='application/json')
            else:
                b = {}
                b['msg'] = False
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(b), content_type='application/json')
```

**Here's my ajax code:**

```
    $(document).on('submit', '#projectForm', function (e) {
    var message;
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url 'users:selectProject' %}',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
            project_id:$('#project').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function (data) {
             message = data.msg;
            console.log(message);
            if(data.msg = 'false'){
                console.log('Message is False');
                $('#message').addClass('show');

            }else if(data.msg = 'true') {
                console.log('Message is True');
                $('#message2').addClass('show');
                $('#enableApi').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#project_btn').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }
    });
})
```

It always display 'Message is False' even if ***console.log('message')*** display true.

what am I doing wrong?

Help me, please!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `=` !== `==` || `===`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the conditional statement

`if(data.msg = 'false'){..}` & `else if(data.msg = 'true'){..}`

This two statements are assigning the value, instead of checking for the condition

Replace single equal(=) with double(==) or triple equals(===). Also note the difference between (`==`) and (`===`). There will be no type conversion in `===`.

`if(data.msg === false){..}` & `else if(data.msg === true){..}`

Comment: Now, even it doesn't run the condition with '=='!

Comment: because true/false !== 'true'/'false'

Comment: what is the datatype of `msg`. Please paste the ajax response

Answer (score 0):

The **==** shouldn't be used here because inspection reports usages of JavaScript equality operators which may cause unexpected type coercions.It is considered a good practice to use the type-safe equality operators **===** instead of its regular counterpart **==**

So, it can be solved by using **===** instead of **==**

```
           if(data.msg === false){
                console.log('Message is False');
                $('#message').addClass('show');

            }else if(data.msg === true) {
                console.log('Message is True');
                $('#message2').addClass('show');
                $('#enableApi').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#project_btn').prop('disabled', true);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
   if(data.msg = 'false'){
```

Should be:

```
  if(data.msg == 'false'){
```

If you want to compare use '==', but if you want to set a value use '='